# Gradient of expected transformed outcome with respect to distribution parameters

Tags: proof

If $x$ has density $p(x \mid \theta)$
why is it true that for some function $f$,
$$\begin{align}
  \nabla_{\theta}\mathbb{E}[f(x)]
  &= \mathbb{E}[f(x) \nabla_\theta p(x)]
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like  "true" (reference please, in case I overlooked something obvious, or a special case). But we can obtain a true relation if in the right hand side we consider the *logarithm* of the density, $\ln[p(x\mid \theta)]$.

For the left hand side we have
$$\nabla_{\theta}\mathbb{E}[f(x)] = \nabla_{\theta}\int p(x\mid \theta)f(x)  dx = \int [\nabla_{\theta}p(x\mid \theta)]\cdot f(x)  dx$$

while for the righthand side using the logarithm of the density we have that

$$ \mathbb{E}\big(f(x) \nabla_\theta \ln[p(x\mid \theta)]\big) = \int p(x\mid \theta)\cdot f(x) \cdot \frac{[\nabla_\theta p(x\mid \theta)]}{p(x\mid \theta)]} dx\\ = \int f(x) \cdot [\nabla_\theta p(x\mid \theta)] dx
$$

So

$$\nabla_{\theta}\mathbb{E}[f(x)] = \mathbb{E}\big(f(x) \nabla_\theta \ln[p(x\mid \theta)]\big)$$